# Keyboard is closing unexpectedly on flutter app, it only happens in android, no exception is thrown

Tags: android, flutter

The keyboard just closes unexpectedly on an specific screen, it does not thrown any error to track

I have tried removing all the BlocBuilders and Location stream updates so the view is only a simple container with a text form field. i did that because I thought that maybe the screen was being updated because of a bloc builder and they keyboard was being closed because of that but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve it, the problem was that I was requesting location permissions unnecessarily every time I changed the field I was writing in, and apparently requesting permissions causes the keyboard to close.

Answer (score 0):

Use GlobalKey for Form

Wrap your TextFormField with a GlobalKey and use it to control the form. This ensures that the form state is preserved across widget rebuilds.

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: TextFormField(
   
  ),
)
```